# Forwarding RDP in tcp tunnel

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, tcpclient, rdp, tunneling

I am creating a TCP tunnel application for RDP connections, On Server-side: Redirecting RDP connections to tunnel-server, Then sending those data to Client-side which *receives the data successfully*. But what happens after that? I don't know!

I know it is easier if traffic was HTTP/HTTPS because you can parse the header to address and content then send back the result. You don't even need TCP or sockets but forwarding RDP is unclear for me.

How can i **forward those traffics from client-side** then sending the results back to server and mstsc (windows default RDP client)? My problem is with the concept, Should i send those RDP data to client then from client machine to port 3389? And this app is considered some sort of **Socks Proxy** i guess.

This is the structure of what i have done at the moment:

[image: Structure of this application in an image]

Similar threads that aren't answer to my issue:

- [RDP through TCP Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821220/rdp-through-tcp-proxy)
- [How to create a simple proxy in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226784/how-to-create-a-simple-proxy-in-c)
- [C# Proxy using Sockets, how should I do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620853/c-sharp-proxy-using-sockets-how-should-i-do-this)

P.S. The type of programming language doesn't matter for me (Currently working with c# and python but newer languages are OK too), I just want to learn how it works conceptually with a simple pseudo-code or sample, All kind of explanations or examples are appreciated.